# App domain when service hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

Question is, Does IIS create seperate app domain for each service call when I have `ConcurrencyMode` as `Multiple` and `InstanceContextMode` as `PerCall` ?

My IIS hosted WCF service contract implementation looks like below

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Serice: IService
{....}
```

Comment: it should be only one app domain.

Comment: why on earth it is down voted ? am i talking nonsense ?

Comment: what research have you done?

Comment: I am trying to set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol between SSL and TLS to serve specific HttpWebRequest. Since ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol is a static variable and change affect across all https request in current appdomain, I was doubtful whether it is possible. To confirm this, I run simulated WCF service invocation through multiple threads and works as expected ( able to set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol on one to one basis). Now I want a second opinion. Hope this help

Comment: IIS create one appDomain per application. An application can be a website or a virtual folder converted to an application. An application can contains a lot of service. By the way, creating an appdomain is a complex and costly operation, IIS is one of the few apps that use appdomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea was to test and ensure how ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol (TLE/SSL) can be conditionally set within IIS to talk to other third party services (based on their transition schedule some service support SSL and some TLE). Therefore the conclusion is only single app domain.